# jQuery addClass when a radio button in a group is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, radio-button

I have the following code:

```
var selectedMarkerClass = 'was-selected';

$('.group_1').change(function() {
    $(this).addClass(selectedMarkerClass);

    if ($('.' + selectedMarkerClass).length == $('.group_1').length) {
        $('#2').removeClass('red');
    }
});
```

Here is the HTML in question:

```
<input class="single_text_input group_1" type="text" name="primary_referral" />
<input class="single_text_input group_1" type="text" name="secondary_referral" />
<input class="group_1" type="radio" name="referral_open" value="Yes" /> Yes
<input class="group_1" type="radio" name="referral_open" value="No" /> No
<span id="2" class="red">Referral Group</span>
```

What is happening now is that both radio buttons in the group have to be changed in order for the class to be removed from the `span`. I would like it to work where only one of the radio buttons in the group has to be changed.

Comment: I apologize for not including it the first go round.  I've updated my post.

Comment: Have you checked the numeric value of .length? write it out to console.info or to the screen.

Comment: What is happening now is that both radio buttons in the group have to be changed in order for the class to be removed from the span. I would like it to work where only one of the radio buttons in the group has to be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `click` event not `change` event.

```
$('.group_1').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass(selectedMarkerClass);

    if ($('.' + selectedMarkerClass).length == $('.group_1').length) {
        $('#2').removeClass('red');
    }
});
```

Update:

```
if ($('.' + selectedMarkerClass).length == $('.group_1').length)
```

Is tripping you up. You are removing the red class only if the selected class has been added to each radio and you can only add the selected class if you click each radio.

A better way would be:

```
$('.group_1').click(function() {
    $('#2').removeClass('red');
});
```

Less code is often times better. You can't unselect a radio. So any click on the radios ensures at least one is clicked.

Comment: This seems to produce the same result as what I have now.  I have to click each of the buttons in the group before it works.

Comment: @user1647550 Added a thoughtful explanation of the problem and a better solution.

Comment: I thank you very much for your time.  Perhaps I am misunderstanding your solution, but what I am trying to accomplish is the removal of a class from a span once all of the input elements of a certain class (group_1) have been clicked (or, preferably, been changed). The input elements will be a mixed bag, radio, text, checkbox, etc... Thank you again for your assistance @anonymous down voting is lame

Comment: @user1647550 Your last comment differs from your OP. You said "I would like it to work where only one of the radio buttons in the group has to be changed." I presented a solution to the problem. I won't continually develop based on your shifting requirements. Sounds like you need a new question.

Comment: You're right.  You correctly answered the question I posed.  I shouldn't have assumed you would follow the path I was already on with the code I supplied. I appreciate your time and effort, and am marking your answer as correct.  Despite the fact that it is useless to me, it is a correct answer to an interpretation of the question I asked, and may be helpful to someone in the future.

Comment: @user1647550 Thanks for honoring the process. Too many new users abuse SO for a 1 question quick fix. Please ask a new question with a fuller explanation, your code thus far, and I will be happy to help. Thanks again.

Comment: Here is my new question with (hopefully) a clear explanation of what I'm facing. Thanks again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393586/jquery-tools-validator-custom-effect-adding-removing-effects @anonymous

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `click` event instead. You see the change take place after the second click because `change` gets fired after the first radio button loses focus.

Answer (score 0):

After both radio button changed, `$('.' + selectedMarkerClass).length == 2` and `$('.group_1').length == 4` because you are using `.group_1` class for radio buttons and as well as for input[type=text] too.

need filter your radio button, use `"[name=referral_open]"`,

```
var selectedMarkerClass = 'was-selected';

$('.group_1').change(function () {
    $(this).addClass(selectedMarkerClass);

    if ($('.' + selectedMarkerClass).length == $('.group_1[name=referral_open]').length) {
        $('#2').removeClass('red');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you @K.K for your answer.  It will work for what I need.  I was trying to avoid this solution because I have so many radio button groups on the form I'm working with (over 4oo fields), and had hoped not to create a script for each set of radio buttons.  Thanks again!