# jQuery Tools Validator Custom Effect - Adding & Removing effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I've worked on this for quite some time now, and am stumped.  I'm hoping someone has some direction for me.  First the code:

The jQuery:

```
$("#paperwork").bind("onFail", function(e, errors)  {
if (e.originalEvent.type == 'submit') {

    $.each(errors, function()  {
        var input = this.input;
        input.parent().css({color: 'red'}).change(function()  {
            input.parent().css({color: '#444'});
        });
    });
}
```

});

And a sampling of the HTML:

```
<input id="group_1" required="required" type="radio" name="attending" value="Yes"  />Yes
<input id="group_1" type="radio" name="attending" value="No"  />No
<input id="group_1" type="radio" name="attending" value="Not Provided" />Not Provided

<input id="group_1" class="single_text_input" type="text" name="primary_referral"  />
<input id="group_1" class="single_text_input" type="text" name="secondary_referral" />
<span class="group_1">Referrals</span>
```

There are several sections that look much like the above.  Each with a corresponding `<span>` (e.g. "2", "3", etc...) What I'm trying to accomplish is this:

When the validator runs, the `.parent()` element of each input turns red. That is working. When the user makes a change to the input, the `.parent()` element returns to its original color. That is also working.

In addition to this, I would like to turn each `input` section's corresponding `<span>` red (text or background). Then, when all the inputs within that section are changed, the corresponding `<span>` is returned to its original appearance. One issue (at least for me) is that the `div` containing the inputs and the corresponding `<span>` do not seem to be related to each other, whether by `.parent()`, `.child()`, or `.closest`.

Answer (score 0):

> One issue (at least for me) is that the div containing the inputs and
>   the corresponding  do not seem to be related to each other,
>   whether by .parent(), .child(), or .closest.

Check if that is true by trying to reach the span in a live console like the Google Chrome Inspector's one.

Answer (score 0):

Just set a class common to those divs, so you can select them later by that class.